# Upload PDF to folder via WebDAV To Folder with Custom Metadata Schema?

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, webdav

Can I upload PDF's to a folder via WebDAV  & have it assigned to a custom schema?  I have WebDAV set up & it works, but can I have the pdf assigned to a custom metadata schema at the same time?

I tried uploading the PDF to a folder that has a linked schema set, but I keep getting an error.  When the linked schema is blank, I can upload to that folder.

**Update**

The error is shown below.  That occurs when I try & copy the PDF to a WebDav folder with a linked schema set.  I can copy the same PDF to a folder that does not have a linked schema.  I'm assuming it's because of the linked schema.  I justed wanted to be sure I wasn't missing anything.

[image]

Comment: Whats the error? Do mandatory fields all have default values?

Comment: As was mentioned - provide error firstly.
Also, you can change metadata/content through event system (WebDav before 2013 used configuration for that, but since 2013 EventSystem can be used).

Comment: See update above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with some caveats on the defaults and authorization.

The [documentation explains the rules for these defaults](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-83691209-E4B8-473E-955D-7142424FAB18). Basically, for a folder with a linked Schema to accept a PDF via WebDAV you need the following:

- The PDF must match (one of) the Mime Type for the folder's Multimedia Schema
- The Multimedia Schema's should either have:

  - No required fields
  - Required fields but with defaults set
- Authorization to do the same for that user (Component rights and write on the folder)
- Same-named items will update (create a new major version) an item if it's "editable" (parent item or localized and maybe checked out). Be careful with same-named items elsewhere in the BluePrint though, which will prevent saving in the Content Manager Explorer and WebDAV.

The mandatory setting also affects how the items is saved. For example, if the Schema is set to a non-Multimedia Schema, you could still load the PDF if the Schema is not marked mandatory (it will default to the Default Multimedia Schema).

I think the issue might be the defaults, but check the list to confirm (or post an answer for what worked).

Comment: Thank you!  The lack of default values was the reason for the error.